# Flume JMS source class not found exception

Tags: apache, jms, cloudera, flume

I want to use `JMS` source for `flume`. I have configured it as follows:

```
...
#Source Definition
a1.sources.r1.type = jms
a1.sources.r1.initialContextFactory =
org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
a1.sources.r1.providerURL = tcp://<ipAddress>:<port>
a1.sources.r1.destinationName = QA.TEST.NAME
a1.sources.r1.destinationType = QUEUE
...
```

I have set flume though `Cloudera`, so all the configuration is done with a global multi-instance UI. 
I have set the Flume Service Environment as follows:

```
...
FLUME_CLASSPATH= .../cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib
```

Where the jms source jar is located.
Though I get the following error:

```
Failed to start agent because dependencies were no found in classpath. Error follows: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Very naive comment, but who knows... You say that you have set this environment variable as `FLUME_CLASSPATH= .../cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib`. Is the `...` a typo when writting the question? Or did you really put those 3 dots?

Comment: The classpath does not contain 3 dots lol. I had this problem with `HBase_HOME`, but I managed to solve it the exact same way as the `FLUME_CLASSPATH`

Comment: Hi @itaied - Did you figure out how to resolve this issue? Could you pls share the solution with me? Thanks.